# What are possible generalizations of higher moments of random vectors

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

I am not very familiar with random vectors beyond the covariance analysis.
Here is my question. 
For a scalar random variable $X$ it is straight forward to define for any $n\in \mathbb{R}$ 
\begin{align}
E[X^n]
\end{align}

However, what about random vectors. For example, generalization of $E[X^2]$ is the autocovarience matrix given by
\begin{align}
E[XX^T]
\end{align}

My question is are generalizations to any other moments?
I guess the generalization where $n$ is even is 
$E[ (XX^T)^n]$ since $(XX^T)$ is a symmetric matrix.  However, what about $n=1.2$?

Thanks for any help. Also, please let me know how I can improve my question.

Comment: You could consider the tensor $E[X_{i_1}\dotsb X_{i_n}]$. But I do not know any useful result around it.

Comment: @user251257 thanks. I will check it. Can you point me to some the reference?

Comment: Like I said, I don't know any results about it. I am not sure if it is really useful. It is just a natural extension.